# Why is the space between each folder so big in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

I want a bigger looking of folders, but the blank space between folders becomes big ,too. Is there any way to fix that?

From this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy way directly in Nautilus itself.
You can however use `dconf-editor`:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
dconf-editor
```

Now navigate to org->gnome->nautilus->icon-view. Try setting bigger values in the *thumbnail-size* field. 128 worked for me. Don't forget to restart nautilus afterwards:

```
killall nautilus
```

It's not a perfect solution as it changes only the size and spacing of pictures/videos thumbnails. Regular icons are unaffected, as their size is by default 48px.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu Tweak Tools.
Navigate to Tweaks tab.
Tweaks > System/File Manager > Thumbnail icon size > 128 or 150 (default is 64)

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)